# por que no puedo obtener los valores de una pagina a otra en php?

Tags: php

Buenas tardes tengo una consulta:

He pasado valores por parámetro `href` desde una pagina a otra .. pero no puedo obtenerlas creo que estoy haciendo todo bien. Por favor revisen para ver que esta mal.

Me doy cuenta que no lo puedo obtener por que cuando quiero ponerlo en el titulo `'REPORTE DE GUIA'.$cid` no me aparece nada solo el `REPORTE DE GUIA`

```
<?php 
require('fpdf.php'); 
$cid = $_GET['id'];
$guia = $_GET['guia'];
$serie = $_GET['nserie'];
//$id = 'hshsashsh';

class PDF extends FPDF 
{ 
  public $sucursal; 
  public $f_ini; 
  public $f_fin; 

  //Cabecera de página 


    function Header() 
    { 

       $this->Rect(1,1,213,31); 
       $this->Rect(1,31,213,1,'DF'); 
        //Logo 
       // $this->Image('../css/images/Logog.jpg',13,2,25,27); 
        //Arial bold 15 
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',14); 
        //Movernos a la derecha 
        $this->Cell(30); 
        //Título 
        $this->Cell(170,4,$cid,0,0,'C'); 
        $this->Ln(2); 
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',10); 
        $this->Cell(36);  
        $this->MultiCell(170,5,'REPORTE DE GUIA'**.$cid**); 
        //$this->SetFont('Arial','',6); 

        $this->SetFont('Arial','',7); 
        $this->Line(1,32,214,32); 

        $this->Text(12,36,'SERIE.'); 
        $this->Text(22,36,'ORDEN'); 
        $this->Text(35,36,'CLIENTE'); 
        $this->Text(95,36,'CANTIDAD');      
        $this->Text(120,36,'FECHA VENCIMIENTO');    
        $this->Line(1,38,214,38); 
        $this->Line(1,39,214,39); 
        //Salto de línea 
        $this->Ln(10); 
        $this->SetY(45);



    }


    //Pie de página 
    function Footer() 
    { 

      //Posición: a 1,5 cm del final 
        $this->SetY(-15); 
        //Arial italic 8 
        $this->SetFont('Arial','I',7); 
        //Número de página 
        $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C'); 
      $fecha= date("Y-m-d"); 
       $hora=date("H:i:s"); 
      $this->Line(1,266,214,266); 
      $this->Line(1,273,214,273); 
      $fecha= date("Y-m-d"); 
       $hora=date("H:i:s"); 
       $this->Text(10,270.5,$fecha); 
        $this->Text(30,270.5,$hora); 
        $this->Text(148,270.5,$this->f_ini); 
        $this->Text(180,270.5,$this->f_fin); 
    } 

    function __construct() 
    {        
        //Llama al constructor de su clase Padre. 
        //Modificar aka segun la forma del papel del reporte 
        parent::__construct('P','mm','Letter'); 
    } 
} 

    //Creación del objeto de la clase heredada 
    $pdf=new PDF(); 
    $pdf->SetTopMargin(5.4); 
    $pdf->SetLeftMargin(4.5);     
    $pdf->AliasNbPages(); 
    $pdf->SetFont('Times','',7); 

$cadconex="dbname=basenex host=192.168.1.10 port=5432 user=postgres password=abc123"; 
$conexion = pg_connect($cadconex); 



        $cadbusca = "select
det.serie as serie,
det.orden as orden,
 max( cli.cliente) as cliente,
CAST(count(*) as integer) as cantidad,
max(ord.fechavencimiento) as fechavencimiento,
det.estadoveri as tpguia,
case when det.estadoveri='MA' then 'DOCUMENTOS MASIVO' when det.estadoveri='CO' then 'DOCUMENTOS COURIER' end destpguia
from despacho des
left outer join detdespacho det on des.serieguia=det.serieguia and des.nroguia = det.nroguia
left outer join personal per on per.codigopersonal=des.codmensajero
left outer join t_empresa emp on emp.codempresa=per.codempresa
left outer join ordenes ord on ord.serie=det.serie and ord.orden = det.orden
left outer join cliente cli on cli.codcliente=ord.codcliente
left outer join sedesprov sede on sede.codsede=des.codsede
where des.serieguia='001' and des.nroguia='761171'
group by det.serie,det.orden,det.estadoveri
order by det.estadoveri,det.serie,det.orden"; 

            $result=pg_query($cadbusca) or die('La consulta fallo: ' . pg_last_error()); 


    $pdf->AddPage();     

         while($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) 
        { 
          $serie = $row["serie"];             
          $orden = $row["orden"]; 
          $cliente = $row["cliente"]; 
          $cantidad = $row["cantidad"]; 
          $fechavencimiento = $row["fechavencimiento"]; 


          $pdf->Text(13,$pdf->GetY(),$serie); 
          $pdf->Text(22,$pdf->GetY(),$orden); 
          $pdf->Text(35,$pdf->GetY(),$cliente); 
          $pdf->Text(100,$pdf->GetY(),$cantidad); 
          $pdf->Text(120,$pdf->GetY(),$fechavencimiento);  
          $pdf->cell(0,5.5,'',0,1); 

        } 

$pdf->Output();

?>
```

Comment: puedes agregar desde donde pasar los datos por parametro en la url?

Answer (score 0):

Estas declarando una clase y dentro de ella no estan defenidas las variables que se encuentran al principio te recomiendo leer la documentacion oficial 
http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.basic.php

un ejemplo de lo que tendrias que hacer seria

```
<?php

class calculadoraEuro{

public $dolar_euro;

// el constructor tiene que ser un metodo publico
public function __construct(){
    $this->dolar_euro = 0.74;
    echo 'El valor del euro es: '. $this->dolar_euro;
}

  public function dolaresEuros( $dolares){
    return $dolares.' dolares son '. ($dolares * $this->dolar_euro) .' euros';  
 }
}
$calculadora = new calculadoraEuro(); 
echo $calculadora->dolaresEuros(5);
 ?>
```

si tienes mas dudas ve a http://codehero.co/php-desde-cero-clases-objetos-parte-ii/